# bjam installation on RedHat centos 7 ppc64

Tags: boost, openstreetmap, redhat, bjam, osrm

I am trying to install OSRM and have followed the instructions on the link below.

But am coming stuck when as I do not seem to ave laubind-0.9.1.

I would like to install `bjam` on my linux system of RedHat Centos 7 ppc64, as I would like to use it to install `luabind-0.9.1` as suggested here: (https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Building-OSRM)

Google searches suggest i need to use `boost`? but im not sure...

Any help would be very helpful...

Answer (score 0):

As the [luabind INSTALL instructions](https://github.com/luabind/luabind/blob/master/INSTALL) suggest, you must install boost-jam which is avaiable at CentOS 7 with yum

```
# yum install boost-jam
```

After that, make sure the file Jamroot has the right reference to the lua library path (of course, lua must be installed)

```
$ grep "local lib" Jamroot
local lib = $(prefix)/lib;
```

In my system (x86_64) I had to change that since LUA was in /usr/lib64.

```
local lib = $(prefix)/lib64;
```

As you said you are using ppc, look for the liblua.so and use that path in Jamroot.

After that, procced with `bjam install`

Or you can use https://github.com/DennisOSRM/luabind and build and install with cmake

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
make 
sudo make install
```

Hope that helps!